# "But since" before "Now"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

Is the word "**since**" needed there before "**now**"? Does it change the meaning?

- I was worried about you but ***since now*** that I know that you are okay I'm okay too.

I made up this sentence but I am not sure whether I need to include "**since**" or omit it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&newwindow=1&q=band+of+gold+lyrics&oq=band+of+gold+lyrics&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l4.11942.15787.0.15916.25.23.1.0.0.0.147.2065.11j9.20.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..4.21.2067.6..35i39k1j0i131k1j0i67k1j0i20k1j0i13k1.uEnQCkaeJq8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence, the word "since" can be left out without changing the meaning. This is because the words "now that" are used for the same purpose of giving a reason.

You could keep with word "since", but it sounds verbose.

On a separate point, you can also omit the second "that" in "not that I know **that** you are okay". It also sounds like there are too many words here, so removing it will remove the repetition without changing the meaning. This will make it sound more natural, like a native's speech.